# Implementing Aptana Studio + Django + Vagrant&Virtual box

Tags: django, aptana, virtualenv, virtualbox, vagrant

I set up my virtual environment via vagrant and virtual box. I use Aptana IDE for django development and I'm wondering if there's a way to integrate new projects in aptana with the VM. 
I've previously used virtualenv and i just change my python path to include my virtualenv directory. However, with virtual box, i'm not sure how to do that. I thought it'd be the same procedure but i don't think so. With Virtualenv, I was able to locate the projects i created within that directory. When I create a project via Vagrant+Virtual Box, I'm not able to locate the project directory anywhere...it's not in the dedicated directory that i setup for virtual environments. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with Vagrant. Let me give you an example:

**I. project structure:**

```
/yourdjangoapp
    /... # all your app stuff here
    /manage.py
/vagrant
    /provisioning
        /init.sh
/Vagrantfile
/.project
```

**II. /Vagrantfile** (simple example w/ default precise64 box):

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "precise64"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant/provisioning/init.sh"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8000
end
```

III. **/vagrant/provisioning/init.sh**

```
if [ ! -f /home/vagrant/.vm_initialized ]
then
    rm -rf /var/www
    ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
    touch /home/vagrant/.vm_initialized
fi
```

**What's happening?**

- Vagrant creates a shared folder for each vm, this defaults to "/vagrant" within the quest os and to the folder where you put your Vagrantfile on the host machine.
- we add a provision shell script to our Vagrant config, so Vagrant will run this after booting the VM
- in /vagrant/provisioning/init.sh we set a symbolic link for the shared folder to /var/www (just an example, so we can access it with apache w/o further configuration)
- as Vagrant will run this on every "vagrant up", we have to check, if the vm is already initialized (if-block in init.sh)

**Where to go from here?**

Well, you could start your development server with:

```
python /var/www/yourdjangoapp/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And should be able to access it from your host machine via

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

You can edit your project on the host w/ your favorite editor now (placed in /yourdjangoapp).

For a new project create/copy the project structure. As Vagrant creates a new VM for each project, the shared folder in the guest is always linked to your current project's folder.

**Working without provisioners**

The current example shows the setup I use. My init.sh includes stuff like installing packages, pulling a GIT repo and so on.

Of course you can omit the provising part and work directly with the shared folder available at /vagrant in the guest os. So you should be able to start the development server with:

```
python /vagrant/yourdjangoapp/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

HTH

Christian